# Why is there ご in 判断

Tags: honorifics, prefixes

I was wondering why there was ご in ご判断.

I saw this in a sentence in anime called *Oregairu* ep. 10.

> それとお手伝いの件　城廻先輩の **ご**判断もありますし

Answer (score 3):

The「ご」in「ご判断」but also the「お」in「お手伝い」both indicate that the speaker is using the honorific register. You may know that there's different levels of politeness in Japanese, and honorific is the highest level of politeness. You use this register when talking to for example your boss or to a professor.「ご」and「お」are two different pronunciations for the same character「御」, which is the honorific prefix. You'll find that it's rarely written as a kanji though.

Look into「敬語{けいご}」if you want to learn more about the honorific register.